# Why does try_files append each path together?

Tags: nginx

I'm using **try_files** like this:

```
http {
  server {
    error_log /var/log/nginx debug;
    listen 127.0.0.1:8080;
    location / {
      index off
      default_type  application/octet-stream;
      try_files /files1$uri /files2/$uri /files3$uri;
    }
  }
}
```

In the error log, it's showing this:

*[error] 15077#0: *45399 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/files1/files2/files3/path/to/my/image.png", client: 127.0.0.1, server: , request: "GET /path/to/my/image.png HTTP/1.1", host: "mydomain.com", referrer: "http://mydomain.com/folder"*

Can anyone tell me why nginx is looking for `/files1/files2/files3/path/to/my/image.png` instead of `/files1/path/to/my/image.png`, `/files2/path/to/my/image.png` and `/files3/path/to/my/image.png`?

Thanks

Answer (score -3, accepted):

The issue was solved by adding a root directive outside the location block:

```
http {
  root /;
  location / {
    try_files files1$uri files2$uri files3$uri =404;
  }
}
```

Comment: No, it was solved because you correctly added the final fallback location.

Comment: You should NEVER put "root /" in your nginx config. You open up the possibility of someone accessing /etc/passwd or some other sensitive file.

Answer (score 7):

http://nginx.org/r/try_files

```
syntax:     try_files file ... uri;
            try_files file ... =code;
```

The last parameter specifies return code or URI for internal redirect. In your case it's `/files3$uri`.

Perhaps you actually want this:
    `try_files /files1$uri /files2$uri /files3$uri =404;`

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that nginx is essentially recursing, because the paths specified in `try_files` are matched by the `location /` block, which applies the `try_files` directive again. Try adding these location blocks to catch the paths which are being searched.

```
location /files1 {}
location /files2 {}
location /files3 {}
```

Comment: You're right about a recursion but you're wrong about what caused it. Please, check the docs: http://nginx.org/r/try_files _Checks the existence of files in the specified order, and uses the first found file for request processing;_ ___the processing is performed in the current context.___

Comment: @VBart I'm not following why that means that `/files1/files2/files3` is finally prepended?

Comment: 0. Assume that `$uri` is `/`.
1. Go to `location /`
2. `/files1$uri` results not found;
3. `/files2/$uri` results not found;
4. Redirecting to `/files3$uri`, because the **last parameter** in `try_files` is **internal redirect**;
5. Go to step 1 with the new `$uri`.

Comment: @VBart Ah, gotcha.